# clear the cache of client web service, python

Tags: python, web-services, soap, suds, spyne

I wrote a simple server-side web service using [spyne](http://spyne.io) on python,
and this is my client-side code:

```
from suds.client import Client
hello_client = Client('http://localhost:8000/?wsdl')
print(hello_client)
```

but when I add another service or changing the name of the service function in the server-side, and then run the client side again. I still get the last web service name.

from this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20217104/create-multiple-services-using-spyne), i understand that my client service keeps the copy of old service as a cache and using that so.
my question is how could I clear the cache of the service?
does python program keeps the cache? or it is from somewhere else?

Comment: run `rm -rf $TMP/suds`

Comment: should I run this command on my Terminal?!  because there is no suds folder/file on my tmp directory